# Django models : format address to long / lat - models not saving

Tags: python, django

I have a question. I'm trying to create a model with address and format it into GPS point.
The issue is when I try to save from admin, all is saved (except long and lat).

On the dashboard of my API, all the request are here. I don't understand what's wrong here.

shop/models.py

```
from opencage.geocoder import OpenCageGeocode

class Supermarket(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=300)
    street = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=300)
    number_street = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=20)
    town = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=60)
    zipcode = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=20)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, blank=True, default='0')
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, blank=True, default='0')
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        
        address = " ".join([self.number_street, self.street, self.zipcode, self.town])
        key = 'xxxx'
        geocoder = OpenCageGeocode(key)
        result = geocoder.geocode(address, no_annotations='1')

        if result:
            self.longitude = result[0]['geometry']['lng']
            self.latitude  = result[0]['geometry']['lat']
            self.save()
            
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I've tried with and everything works well: So I don't really understand what's wrong here

```
>>> from opencage.geocoder import OpenCageGeocode
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> key = 'xxxxx'
>>> query = u'XXXXX'
>>> results = geocoder.geocode(query)
>>> print(u'%f;%f;%s;%s' % (results[0]['geometry']['lat'],
...                         results[0]['geometry']['lng'],
...                         results[0]['components']['country_code'],
...                         results[0]['annotations']['timezone']['name']))
XX.XXXXXX;X.XXXXXX;fr;Europe/Paris
```

**UPDATE - IT WAS REALLY EASY**

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        supermarket = super().save()
        
        address = " ".join([self.number_street, self.street, self.zipcode, self.town])
        result = geocoder.geocode(address)

        if result and len(result):
            self.longitude = result[0]['geometry']['lng']
            self.latitude  = result[0]['geometry']['lat']
            
        super(Supermarket, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: you give string default value for longitute and latituede fields, while they get integer values

Comment: Do you mean I have to change longitude = models.DecimalField of longitude = models.IntegerField (without default). Sorry I'm beginning

Comment: I think, in your `models.py` you did wrong implementation for `save` method

Comment: could you please correct my save method?

Comment: you made recursion, so if you want implement your `save` method not recursivly that you must give `commit=True` in default parameters

Comment: thanks I'll try with the code below

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
key = 'xxxx'
geocoder = OpenCageGeocode(key)

class Supermarket(models.Model):
    ...

    def save(self, commit=True):
        supermarket = super().save(commit=False)

        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        address = " ".join([self.number_street, self.street, self.zipcode, self.town])
        result = geocoder.geocode(address, no_annotations='1')

        if result and commit:
            self.longitude = result[0]['geometry']['lng']
            self.latitude  = result[0]['geometry']['lat']
            supermarket.save()
```

Comment: no need *args,**kwargs? Cause I got a fatal issue 'We're sorry, but something went wrong.
The issue has been logged for investigation. Please try again later.'

Comment: I had to delete this def __str__(self):return self.name. The issue is solved but right now I got this, save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'